# Android set locale of Textview and EditText

Tags: android, locale

I'm building an app where I am explicitly setting the locale of the app to **Arabic**. However, I want to collect phone numbers in **English**.
How can I set explicitly the locale of EditText and TextView to USA **English**.

Below is how I am setting the app locale.
I have this helper class

```
public class LocaleHelper extends ContextThemeWrapper {

    public LocaleHelper(Context base) {
        super(base, R.style.MyTheme);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (!language.equals("")) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
                context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
            } else {
                context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
        return new LocaleHelper(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
        return config.locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

and inside my activity I use this helper in `attachBaseContext` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.wrap(newBase, "ar"));
}
```

How can I set the locale of an EditText or a TextView to **US** separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the custom font applied to the `EditText` didn't have **English** numbers, only **Arabic** numbers so no matter what I tried, only the **Arabic** numbers would show up which makes sense.

Comment: I've the same issue, although my font has the english and arabic numbers. So can you share what have you tried?

Comment: I ended up not setting the locale programmatically and then used an Arabic font with English numbers and setting the alignment to right.
It's hacky but couldn't find a better solution.

Comment: You can edit your font. Use FontForge and copy the English digits glyphs and paste them into Arabic-Hindi Digits glyphs then generate the font.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.format()` with `Locale.ENGLISH` to show english numbers instead of arabic ones

example

```
String txtPrice = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d", item.getPrice());
mItemPriceTextView.setText(txtPrice);
```